# How can I disable signing with ws policy for a specific token type?

Tags: web-services, cxf, ws-security

I have a secure token service (CXF). It works fine, if the user signs the message (wsse:BinarySecurityToken) to authenticate.

Now the same service must be used, if the user supplies a username token. In this case the user must not sign the message. I can not give him a different webservice address - which would make this really easy - to call.

I have already implemented the UsernameTokenValidator and everything works, when I remove my current policy:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="CertificateSecurityPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:Layout>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:Lax/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
            <sp:IncludeTimestamp wsp:Optional="true"/>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body/>
                <sp:Header Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
                <wsu:Timestamp/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

But if I remove this, then the signing is not mandatory and it breaks the first use case.

Any idea how I should approach this? Can the policy be modified in a way, that signing is not mandatory for username token ?:

```
 <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" >
   <wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

Or should I remove all policies? In this case? Will the X509 Validator be triggerd if the user signs the message and supplies a wsse:BinarySecurityToken?

**Edit:**

Here is the solution to my problem thanks to Colm O hEigeartaigh h

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="issuePolicy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:Layout>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Lax/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Layout>
                <sp:IncludeTimestamp wsp:Optional="true"/>
                <sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:Body/>
                    <sp:Header Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
                    <wsu:Timestamp/>
                </sp:SignedParts>
                <wssp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </wssp:SupportingTokens>
            </wsp:All>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:Layout>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Lax/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Layout>
                <wssp:SupportingTokens> 
                    <wsp:Policy> 
                        <wssp:UsernameToken wssp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"> 
                            <wsp:Policy> 
                                <wssp:WssUsernameToken11/> 
                            </wsp:Policy> 
                        </wssp:UsernameToken> 
                    </wsp:Policy> 
                </wssp:SupportingTokens>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a policy alternative. See here for example: https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/services/sts/systests/basic/src/test/resources/org/apache/cxf/systest/sts/deployment/ws-trust-1.4-service.wsdl#L617